# Is it possible to run a program as both Ruby and PERL?

Tags: ruby, perl

Is it possible to run a program as both Ruby and PERL. If so, are you able to detect the change and print something like "This is a perl program" for perl compiler and "This is a Ruby program" for a ruby compiler

Comment: See [PHP + Perl + Python + Ruby + C + C++ - polyglot](https://gist.github.com/SaswatPadhi/2872457).

Comment: The name of the language is Perl, not PERL. It's not an acronym

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This kind of program is called a [polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/write-a-polyglot-that-prints-the-languages-name/7280#7280). For Perl and Ruby, one useful insight is that [`$stdin` is a defined, initialized variable in Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html)

```
print $stdin ? "This is a Ruby program" : "This is a Perl program";
```